# text triangle in python new line not working in doctest

Tags: python, loops, newline

`python 3.5 Spyder`

For some reason my output includes the \n characters printed instead of carrying out an actual new line. I think my position of the \n is incorrect and i've tried placing it in multiple locations but I haven't seen any improvements.

For eg : text_triangle(5) results in:

`X\\nXX\\nXXX\\nXXXX\\nXXXXX\\nXXXXX\\nXXXX\\nXXX\\nXX\\nX\\n`

python docs mentioned using raw doc strings when using backslashes but that didn't change the output either. I feel that my code does return the right number of characters but how to get the new lines to occur is a mystery to  me.

```
def text_triangle(height):
"""(int) -> string

Returns a text version of an isosceles triangle built from 'X' characters
with height copies of the X in the longest line.  The triangle is returned
in a multiline string.  The string is empty if height <= 0.

For instance, if we call print( text_triangle(5))it will print the following:
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X

>>> text_triangle(0)
''
>>> text_triangle(1)
X
>>> text_triangle(3)
X
XX
XXX
XX
X
>>> text_triangle(5)
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X
"""

if(height <= 0):
    return ''
else:
    out_string = ''
    for i in range(0, height):
        out_string +=  'X' * (i+1) + '\\n'

    for i in range(height, 0, -1):
        out_string +=  'X' * i + '\\n'

    return out_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print(doctest.testmod(verbose = True,
                    optionflags = doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `\\n` in your string. `\` is used to escape the character i.e it will add that character to the string that can not be added directly like `"` can be added as `\"` and `\` can be added as `\\`.

In your code `\\` will add `\` to your string and then `n` is added.

So use `\n` instead of `\\n`.